# Using ReadKey to have more than one "password"?

Tags: c#, passwords

So I am just messing around creating a little program using the console that will show you things depending on the "password" you type. So at the moment when you type the password POKEMON it takes you to a database. But I would like so if you type something like PASSWORD then it takes you to another database. I am not sure how to do it, I was hoping it would be as easy as just saying "if they type POKEMON take them here and if they type PASSWORD take them here" but I am having real trouble. Appreciate the help.

```
namespace Films
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello Jake. Security check: Please type the security code for a database.");
            while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.P) {}
            while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.O) {}
            while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.K) {}
            while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.E) {}
            while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.M) {}
            while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.O) {}
            while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.N) {}
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("\n Passcode entered successfully.");
                while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.O) { }
                while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.K) { }
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n \n                       Loading Database");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("Test");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Console.ReadLine() returns everything the user entered before hitting the return key, that would seem to be a better way to do this.  You can then examine the text with switch() and do what you need.

Comment: Baked in creds are trivial to extract from your executable and therefore pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method called [Console.ReadLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The ReadLine method reads a line from the standard input stream.
>
> If the standard input device is the keyboard, the ReadLine method blocks until the user presses the **Enter** key.

In your case, you'd use it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello Jake. Security check: Please type the security code for a database.");

// This will read all the characters until the user presses Enter
string password = Console.ReadLine();

switch (password)
{
    case "POKEMON":
    {
        // Load some database
        break;
    }
    case "PASSWORD":
    {
        // Load another database
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid password");
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much! :D